# Can I use Stopwatch in release mode?

Tags: c#, stopwatch

In a console app I want to output at the end this:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Finished Analyze with duration: " + watch.Elapsed);
```

Are there any side effects in using the Stopwatch class, when the assembly is build in the release mode?

Or is Stopwatch really only for debugging purposes?

Comment: No, [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) is not meant to be used only for debugging. Use it for whatever you want.

Comment: Or in the affirmative: *Yes*, Stopwatch can be used in Release builds.